# How to disable the progress bar in DeepFace library?

Tags: python, deepface

I am using the DeepFace library to analyze emotions in a video. Here is the relevant code:

```
import cv2
from deepface import DeepFace

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")

prev_emotion = None
prev_time = 0

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    # Analyze emotions in the frame
    result = DeepFace.analyze(frame, actions=['emotion'], enforce_detection=False)

    # Get the dominant emotion
    dominant_emotion = result[0]['dominant_emotion']

    # Get the current time
    current_time = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) / 1000

    # Check if the emotion has changed
    if dominant_emotion != prev_emotion:
        # Check if this is the first emotion or not
        if prev_emotion is not None:
            print(f"{current_time:.2f} seconds: Emotion changed from {prev_emotion} to {dominant_emotion}")

        # Update the previous emotion and time
        prev_emotion = dominant_emotion
        prev_time = current_time

cap.release()
```

When I run this code, it displays a progress bar showing the emotion detection progress for each frame.

Sample output for a frame:

```
Action: emotion: 100%|██████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 18.19it/s]
```

I would like to disable this progress bar as it is not necessary for my use case.

Is there a way to disable the emotion detection progress bar in the DeepFace library? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set silent argument of analyze function to True as mentioned in its [docstring](https://github.com/serengil/deepface/blob/master/deepface/DeepFace.py#LL236C5-L236C11).

```
DeepFace.analyze("img.jpg", actions = ["emotion"], silent = True)
```